# Angular 4 Simple Line Chart without fixed x-axis values

Tags: angular, charts, line

I'm turning crazy as I'm unable to find a library for the most simple Line Graph you can think of: define a (double) min and max value for the x axis and feed it tuples of (x,y) values. Every solution I could find is obsessed with the fact that I have a fixed set of x values (monday, tuesday, thursday,...) but NO I have simple double values in a defined range!

Solutions that are unable to do this simple task: ng2-charts, ngx-charts, Highcharts Angular 2, Fusion Charts Angular2

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: Im confused at what you are asking. something like this?http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-arrays/

Comment: ngx-charts is built with d3.js, you can edit the code to literally draw *anything* you want

Comment: @LLai Thank you so much!!! I wasn't aware that Highcharts supported two dimensional values in the data array.

Comment: You can use ngx-charts for this. See https://plnkr.co/edit/KhOBz1c61aQK0BcXHrPv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [primeng line chart](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart/line) its simple and powerfull.

import

> ```
> import {ChartModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
> ```
>
> in your module

In order for chart component to work, include charts.js to your project. An example with CLI would be;

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
  //..others
],
```

**Component**

```
export class LineChartDemo {

data: any;

msgs: Message[];

constructor() {
    this.data = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'First Dataset',
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: '#4bc0c0'
            },
            {
                label: 'Second Dataset',
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: '#565656'
            }
        ]
    }
}


}
```

**HTML**

```
 <p-chart type="line" [data]="data"></p-chart>
```

Comment: No, this is exactly what I don't want. This only supports a fixed set of x values, which have a defined "one after the other" order. I need to be able to set arbitrary x values. @LLai offered a solution using Highcharts.